# Converting function to promise chain in Lambda

Tags: javascript, function, promise, aws-lambda

I am trying to convert my lambda code to run in a promise chain, but I'm not certain of the proper method to approach this. I am trying to modify my current code to run these actions, `send email -> add to newsletter list if checkbox is checked`, but my email portion runs successfully and then throws an error after I try to chain the `add to newsletter` function after `generateResponse(result, 200)`

Here is my error:

```
TypeError: generateResponse(...).then is not a function
```

Here is the code:

Main function:

```
module.exports.sendEmail = async event => {

  const { body } = event;
  const data = JSON.parse(body);

  try {
    const result = await messageContent(data);
    return generateResponse(result, 200)
      .then(function(){
        if(data.subscribe == "on"){
          return addToNewsletter(data.from, data.topic)
            .then(function(result){
              return generateResponse(result, 200);
            });
        }
      });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

};
```

**generateResponse:**

```
const generateResponse = (body, statusCode) => {
  console.log("generateResponse")
  console.log(body)
  return {
      headers: {
          "access-control-allow-methods": "POST",
          "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
          "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      statusCode: statusCode,
      body: `{\"result\": ${body.message}}`
  };
};
```

**addToNewsletter:**

```
const addToNewsletter = (email, topic) => {
  const mg = mailgun({apiKey: API_KEY, domain: NEWSLETTER_DOMAIN});

  const list = mg.lists(`newsletter@{DOMAIN}`);
  console.log(list)

  const subscriber = {
    address: email,
    vars: {
      topic: topic
    },
    subscribed: "yes",
    upsert: "yes"
  };

  console.log(subscriber);

  return list.members().create(subscriber, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any promise from generateResponse function. Hence the error `.then() is not a function`. Try changing your function to return a promise like below.

```
const generateResponse = (body, statusCode) => {
  console.log("generateResponse")
  console.log(body)
  return Promise.resolve({
      headers: {
          "access-control-allow-methods": "POST",
          "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
          "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      statusCode: statusCode,
      body: `{\"result\": ${body.message}}`
  });
};
```